# Is it possible to use' cover off' instead of 'cover up'?

Tags: word-usage

Is it possible to use' cover off' instead of 'cover up'?

cover up sense of unworthiness

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Cover off" meaning "cover"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34963/cover-off-meaning-cover)

Answer (score 2):

In certain circumstances, perhaps; but not generally.

(This observation, by the way, applies to virtually all English phrasal verb constructions.)

The sole example given is ***cover up sense of unworthiness***, which is certainly not a complete sentence, much less grammatical English -- no subject, no articles, no context.

However, it **does** appear to notice that *cover up* is an English phrasal verb. This is correct. The rest of the question seems to want to know what other particles can be used besides *up* with this meaning, and the answer is ***generally speaking, none***. Occasionally one or another might be, but none can be relied on.

*Cover up* is an illustrative example. The phrasal verb *cover up* means something like '(try to) hide from view (completely)'. The 'completely' part is due to the completive sense of the particle *up*. This is also what makes *burn down* and *burn up* equivalent in

- *The house burned down.*
- *The house burned up.*

If it burned to the ground, it *burned down*; but if it burned to the ground, it burned completely, so it also *burned up*. Similarly, if you *drink down* your beer, then you drink it completely, so you *drink it up*. Etc.

You can say *cover off*, but it doesn't mean the same thing.

- *Take the cover off before you leave.*

is in fact an example of the phrasal verb *take off*, with *the cover* as its direct object, and Particle Shift from

- *Take off the cover before you leave.*

So *cover off* isn't a constituent, but just a random string. Certainly not a phrasal verb.

*Cover Down* has similar problems, though that happens to be, in fact, the name of a [band in Dallas](http://www.coverdownband.com) that [my son](http://www.coverdownband.com/#!Ian%20solo%20at%20Lochrann%27s%20Pub/image235y) plays with. However, I don't think that's the meaning you're looking for, either.

Comment: I took my hat *off* to you.

Comment: Actually *cover off* is becoming a phrasal verb in Bizspeak. Meetings have agenda items to "cover off" (ie which discussions should cover/encompass).

Comment: That's interesting. Does one cover the items off, one by one, or does the meeting cover them off? Can they be covered off, and can you say you're covering them off as fast as you can?